# "wifi not working" on HP ENVY x360 - 15-w107ne

Tags: drivers, wireless, hp

Just a standard wifi-not-working question. A fresh Ubuntu 16.04 and is up to date. Laptop model number in title.

I used the "Wireless info script" in the [accepted answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and there's the result:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/23255392/

*TIA :)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer-wmi.conf <<< "blacklist acer_wmi"
```

and reboot.

This solution is helpful for laptop models when the rfkill shows `acer-wireless` and it is blocked.

Comment: "you can accept an answer in 7 minutes" thank youuu :'D ...this command appends the line `blacklist acer_wmi` into the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer-wmi.conf` right?

Comment: Correct. You can do it manually, if you like it ;-)

Comment: hehe yeah. how did this line fix the problem? plz tell me (briefly) if you have some time to spare :D

Comment: The `acer_wmi` module blocks your wireless. A better way is to add a quirk specific to your laptop model to avoid it. But in most cases blacklisting `acer_wmi` is good enough. This lines prevents loading of `acer_wmi`.

Comment: I see. okay thx again :)

Comment: @Pilot6 It will be great if you could expand the answer with what you said in the footnote. Since this is a model specific fix, we don't want others with wifi not working for other reasons to try this.

Comment: I added a note to the question. But there is no harm if someone uses this solution on a wrong laptop. It should not brake anything ;-)