# Problem using RTL8723be chip

Tags: wireless, hp, realtek, rtl8723be

I've got a big problem with RTL8723be. My WiFi doesn't work, it never works. I've tried all the possible solutions written on internet and on AskUbuntu. The chip is installed on a HP p215nl , what can i do?

EDIT: I've tried Pilot's answer. [How do I get a Realtek RTL8723BE wireless card to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/how-do-i-get-a-realtek-8723be-wireless-card-to-work) .
Bluetooth works perfectly, Wireless Network is totally absent.

EDIT 2: rfkill list output:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy2: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

EDIT 3: Tried ["wifi not working" on HP ENVY x360 - 15-w107ne](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831578/wifi-not-working-on-hp-envy-x360-15-w107ne) And still not working

EDIT 4: Yep, sure. I forgot to say that one of them is an external wireless adapter. This is the output without it.

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

EDIT 5: I haven't that option in my BIOS settings. I've tried moksb command but it gave me an error.

EDIT 6: sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
sudo modprobe rtl8723be msi=1

After these commands i was able to connect through WiFi.

Comment: Please describe what really happens and what have you tried.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `rfkill list`.

Comment: I see two wireless devices.

Comment: Did you disable Secure Boot?

Comment: What is the result of: 'lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`?